# Getting the last element of a form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner in programming and am stuck in a problem. I want to find the last child (element) of parent (form). Then I want to insert an input element after the last child but it should be inside the form not after the form (outside). The form might contain input elements as well as select elements. How to accomplish it? I have tried the following ways but they don't work unfortunately.

```
var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.form-to-be-submitted:last');  // this one gives me the whole form meaning if I add something it will added at the end of the form
var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.form-to-be-submitted input:last'); //this gives me the last input element
var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.form-to-be-submitted input select').last();  //this does nothing, I think its an error

$newSection = $('<input type="button" value="newbutton" name="mybutton"/>');
newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);    // when I use this statement it adds after the form not inside the form
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just need some guidance on CSS Selectors and Jquery methods.

First lets look at:

> The form might contain input elements as well as select elements.

So in CSS to do an `or` you need to use a comma:

```
input,select
```

if you are looking for direct descendants you need to use a `>`

```
form > input, form > select
```

These are then wrapped in jquery:

```
$('form > input, form > select')
```

Which yields all items, so we use [last()](https://api.jquery.com/last) to grab the last element:

```
var $last = $('form > input, form > select').last();
```

(if you don't need the `>` just remove it).

This was pretty close:

```
var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.form-to-be-submitted input select').last();
```

but it's looking for a select element in a input element in that class.  Just needs a little adjustment:

```
var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.form-to-be-submitted input, .form-to-be-submitted select')
  .last();
```

If you want to insert the element at the end of a specific element, you don't need to find the last item.  Just use [jquery's append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Except:

Consider the following HTML:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

You can create content and insert it into several elements at once:

```
$( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Each inner  element gets this new content:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    Hello
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    Goodbye
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It adds the button after the last element in the form!

Comment: I wanted to insert after the last element not in all the elements. The above code worked. Cheers :D

Comment: If you only have one `.form-to-be-submitted` it would only append one div *in that element*

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('.form-to-be-submitted').children().last()
```

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will select all the children in your form and [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) filters that further to only select the last child.

And to insert content after that element, just use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) like:

```
$('.form-to-be-submitted').children().last().after('<input>')
```

Example:

```js
$('.form-to-be-submitted').children().last().after('<input type="radio">')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-to-be-submitted">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <select>
<option></option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if he's looking for `input` or `select` elements.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @ErikPhilips As the snippet shows, it works exactly as it should, and with either input, select, textarea, button, or any other child.

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle where the last element is a DIV and returns DIV](https://jsfiddle.net/gqq8c56z/).  Not the input element.

Comment: @ErikPhilips So what? AFAIK the OP wants a new element inserted just before `</form>`, so what does it matter what kind of element is the last one within the form as long as a new element is inserted after it?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Of course it will return the div. That's what it's supposed to do: "I want to find the last child (element) of parent (form)". If the OP needs to filter it for only inputs and selects then it's a simple matter of changing `.children()` to `.children('input, select')`

Answer (score 0):

JQuery not needed. To insert a new element just before the end of the form, simply use **[`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)**.

```js
var frm = document.getElementById("theForm");  // Get reference to form

// Create a new element and configure it
var newElement = document.createElement("input");
newElement.id = "txtUser";

// Simply append it to the form.
frm.appendChild(newElement);

console.log(frm.elements[frm.elements.length-1]);  // Get last element in form
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
  <input type="text">
  <select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>    
  </select>
  
  <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</form>
```